# "npm run hot" throwing error after installing npm and vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, laravel-8

Below is a complete log of the error-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'hot'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prehot', 'hot', 'posthot' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prehot: @
6 info lifecycle @~hot: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~hot: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~hot: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist\node_modules\.bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist\node_modules\.bin;;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\Anaconda\Library\usr\bin;D:\Anaconda\Library\bin;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle @~hot: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist
10 silly lifecycle @~hot: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'mix watch --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~hot: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~hot: Failed to exec hot script
13 verbose stack Error: @ hot: `mix watch --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\todolist
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "hot"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ hot: `mix watch --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ hot script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I get this error when i run the command "npm run hot" after installing npm and vue and setting up everything needed for vue.js

Comment: Same, have you found an answer yet?

Comment: Having the same problem

Comment: A solution just here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820995/5453732