# "npm run hot" in Laravel project throws invalid configuration error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, phpstorm

I am having a `laravel` project with `vue.js` and when I try to execute `npm run hot` it throws an error.

```
OS: Windows 10
PhpStorm: 2021.2
Vue.js: 3.1.5
Laravel: 8
```

Project dependencies (`npm list --depth 0`):

```
+-- axios@0.21.1
+-- laravel-mix@6.0.27
+-- lodash@4.17.21
+-- postcss@8.3.6
`-- vue@3.1.5
```

Terminal output:

```
> mix watch --hot


* Mix █████████████████████████  (0%)


[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Object has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema
.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'webpackbar'. These properties are valid:
   object { bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, firewall?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, liveRe
load?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, public?, setupExitSignals?, static?, tran
sportMode?, watchFiles? }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ hot: `mix watch --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ hot script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-17T08_43_49_956Z-debug.log
```

Log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'hot'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.14
3 info using node@v14.17.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prehot', 'hot', 'posthot' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prehot: @
6 info lifecycle @~hot: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~hot: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~hot: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\mywebsite.com\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\mywebsite.com\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;;C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin;C:\PHP;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2021.1.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~hot: CWD: C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\mywebsite.com
10 silly lifecycle @~hot: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'mix watch --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~hot: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~hot: Failed to exec hot script
13 verbose stack Error: @ hot: `mix watch --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\mywebsite.com
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "hot"
18 verbose node v14.17.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.14
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error @ hot: `mix watch --hot`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the @ hot script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

[This recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773260/npm-run-hot-throwing-error-after-installing-npm-and-vue) seems to have a similar problem with no solution.

**Attempted solution (same error)** - adding this code to `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.override(config => {
    // Apply a workaround caused by Laravel Mix using the `webpack-dev-server@v4.0.0-beta`:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.3.
    // Basically the `dev` property has been deprecated in favor of `devMiddleware`.
    if (config.devServer) {
        config.devServer.devMiddleware = config.devServer.dev;
        delete config.devServer.dev;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with comptability version, and the package @webpack-cli/serve on 1.5.2 version.

1. Remove your node_modules folder and package-lock.json.
2. Add this in your package.json :

   "@webpack-cli/serve": "1.5.1",

   "webpack-cli": "4.7.2"
3. Run **npm install**
4. Run **npm run hot**

It works with "laravel-mix": "6.0.27".